# How to present new math in conferences?

Tags: education

I research theoretical physics and often some new mathematical model or procedure is my product.  However, whenever I try to present my research at a conference the time limit (or my ability to present) leaves the audience just staring.  At some level I expect this behavior because I think it takes a lot of time and effort to really understand math at a deep enough level to provide useful insights.  However, I can't help but wonder if there are tips or tricks for improving my ability to present my ideas.  Thus, my question is: What are some effective ways to communicate complicated mathematical concepts in a limited period of time?

Comment: Timothy Gowers' dictum: **Examples first!**

Comment: 1) Know what your audience does and does not know.  2) Give the simplest example of the core idea... not the full details.  3) Present the ideas visually... graphs, figures, etc.  4) Make analogies to things the audience knows.  5) Avoid jargon.  6) Use the simplest notation ($x$ instead of $\xi_{\alpha}^k$.  7) Practice with colleagues.  8) Study master lecturers.  9) Realize you won't wow *everyone* in your audience.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is an answer (that I'd love to upvote).

Answer (score 5):

1. Know what your audience does and does not know.
2. Give the simplest example of the core idea... not the full details.
3. Present the ideas visually... graphs, figures, etc.
4. Make analogies to things the audience knows.
5. Avoid jargon.
6. Use the simplest notation ($x$ instead of $\xi_{\beta}^k$).
7. Practice with colleagues.
8. Study master lecturers.
9. Realize you won't wow everyone in your audience, and that's OK.